# Como puedo llamar a la clase DiffCallback en el adapter?

Tags: android, kotlin

Hola estoy intentando llamar la clase DiffCallBack desde el adapter pero me marca error, donde deberia colocar la llamada a la clase ?  les coloco el codigo del adapter y ver si me pueden auxiliar, no tengo mucho conocimiento de hecho voy empezando.

class AdapterComida(private val food : List,private val itemClickListener: OnItemClickListener)
:RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

```
private class DiffCallback : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<DataFood>() {
    override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: DataFood, newItem: DataFood): Boolean {
        return oldItem.comida == newItem.comida
    }
    override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: DataFood, newItem: DataFood): Boolean {
        return oldItem.comida == newItem.comida
    }
}

inner class ItemRvMenuViewHolder(private val binding: ItemRvMenuBinding): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root){
    fun bindMenuView(dataFood:DataFood){
        binding.tvMenu.text=dataFood.comida
        binding.tvDay.text=dataFood.dia
    }
}
inner class ItemRvComidasViewHolder(private val binding: ItemRvComidasBinding):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root){
    fun bindComidasView(dataFood: DataFood,clickListener: OnItemClickListener){
        binding.tvComida.text=dataFood.comida
        binding.IbtnEdit.setOnClickListener { clickListener.onItemEditar(adapterPosition, dataFood) }
        binding.IbtnDelete.setOnClickListener { clickListener.onItemBorrar(adapterPosition) }

    }
}
```